# Stop URL Decode on PHP Redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `go.php` redirecting to `page.php` using `header(...);` but my server keeps turning the symbols `{` and `}` into `%7B` and `%7D`.

What changes do I make so my url stays as `http://www.example.com/page.php?model={model}` and not `http://www.example.com/page.php?model=%7Bmodel%7D` after the redirect?

Comment: Is this causing an issue? Or can you just call `urlencode`/`urldecode` when reading that value from `$_GET` ?

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work.... You can later acces that value en then decode it back to *"normal"* characters.